# Products intrusion in multistore installation

Tags: products

I have a Magento installation with 2 stores, 2 languages each.
I have a custom home page for all the stores for which I use a 2 dedicated featured-products.phhml for each (2) custom templates (ITA-ENG) with a custom block template in the home page content like

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="397" template="catalog/product/featured_products.phtml" sort_by="price" default_direction="desc"}}
```

Store 1 Language 2 home page shows products from a different store (different category root, of course)

Comment: PS: I am using flat catalog and flat category

Comment: I have just noticed that the problem occurs only in the home page, where the products are shown through the featured_products.phtml page. The phtml file hasn't changed since I made it. I tried to clean the cache and I also tried to rename the file. Problem still there.